# Is it possible to add anUIImage over a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm working on a project for school and I was wondering if there was any possible way to add an `UIImage` over a `UIWebView`?

I'm trying to 'blur out' a certain section of an article that I load. I figure that'll be possible by adding an `UIImage`?

Is there a better way to do this?

Basically the purpose is to make a section of the `UIWebView` blurry, and then include a button over the blur asking a user to unlock that section by clicking the `UIButton`. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to blurr part of UIWebView (for example bottom half of view) or to blurr some of webView's html content (for example div with id somethingToBlurr)?

Comment: How would you know where to put the blurring image?